# Advanced Profiling javascript in browsers

Tags: javascript, profiling

I'm currently looking for a good tool to profile javascript in browser. What problems i have with what I currently use:
**Chrome** - When I start profiling after reloading page, it takes infinity to load page. Not possible to finish
**Firefox** - Profiling with firebug is not easily readable (summary of each function in total). __For example

I'm looking for a profile, that would allow me to see not only how much time each function "ate". But analyze each call and subcalls.

Something simmiliar to KCacheGrind display.

Comment: @[one that voted to close] Since when debugging/profiling code is not part of programming? I'm not asking why my code is not working, its general question about best possibilities of profiling scripts. It is a part of programming as far as I see it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert your app to the stand alone app, and if profiling on device is suitable for you, you can use Intel XDK and different profiling types under it. You can find out more info by this link: https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/using-the-profile-tab

The differences between CDT and XDK profilers are follow

- CPU profiler - XDK is annotating source file by the time spent by the lines, not only call tree
- Memory profiler - XDK profiler is more function centric and points which functions (call tree) allocate memory and annotate source view by the self and total memory allocated by the line. You can see bottom-up view and see the hotspot allocating more or switch to the callee view and analyze which high level function implicitly allocates a lot through library calls.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tool I wrote: http://yellowlab.tools

It spies and logs every JS access to the DOM on page load. Perfect tool to understand what's going on and to optimize browser-side JS performances.

Just launch a test then click the "JS Timeline" tab.